# Twilio Studio - Sent message information immediately before reply on send and wait reply widget

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I am looking to get the sent message information immediately after it is sent through the send and wait reply widget without having to wait for a reply to be received.

I can transition from a reply, no reply and delivery failed state however I would like to be able to log that the SMS was sent before we get a reply as the no reply timeout will be set for a number of days.

Is this possible within Twilio Studio?

I have tried to use the messaging service callback status however this was not working as required.